# Changing the directory where .pyc files are created

Tags: python, path, python-3.x, pyc

Is there a way to change the directory where `.pyc` file are created by the Python interpreter? I saw two PEPs about that subject ([0304](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0304/) and [3147](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/)), but none seems to be implemented in the default interpreter (I'm working with Python 3).

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you want to move them?

Comment: It was just out of curiosity, to keep directories clean.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I have a case where the directories with the source files are not writable, and want to relocate the pycache so that all users can benefit from the cache without having write access to the actual python source file directories.

Comment: Would you consider changing the accepted answer here

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no way to change where the .pyc files go.  Python 3.2 implements the `__pycache__` scheme whereby all the .pyc files go into a directory named `__pycache__`.  Python 3.2 alpha 1 is available now if you really need to keep your directories clean.

Until 3.2 is released, configure as many tools as you can to ignore the .pyc files.

Comment: Your custom .py files get compiled and stored in .pyc file under `__pycache__` folder in same directory. You will find common compiled files under `C:\Python34\Lib\__pycache__`.

Comment: This answer is outdated, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60024195/880783

Answer (score 49):

Yes, starting from Python 3.8 you can control this behavior. The original discussion starts from [pep 304](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0304/) in 2003.

> While this original PEP was withdrawn, a variant of this feature was
>   eventually implemented for Python 3.8 in https://bugs.python.org/issue33499

In the result, you can control using [`PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX), [`-X pycache_prefix=path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX) and [`sys.pycache_prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.pycache_prefix).

Comment: for linux users who do not care what happens with the pycache, this will work very well when added to .bashrc: `export PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=/tmp`. The cache files will be sent `/tmp` and will be cleared after 10 days or on system reboot.

Comment: `/tmp` works for macos too!  Even better, `export PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=/tmp/pycache` will put all the files under pycache, creating it if needed.  The advantage is that you can delete the cache easily - I've had problems deleting/renaming .py files but a forgotten import under the old name "finding" the .pyc somewhere.

Answer (score 25):

This might be useful for some:
[Miscellaneous options](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options), especially [`-B`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id1) option:

> If given, Python won’t try to write .pyc files on the import of source
>   modules. See also `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`.

Answer (score 0):

Python files are NOT always stored in the same directory and will get directed to pycache if you use pycache. Any answers on being able to have custom locations and names, because importing the module is rather temperamental and doesn't always work. You will be able see what I mean at github.com/LolexInc/Lolex-Tools/tree/Beta and view JTToolsInstaller.py. There is a lot of mess in it.