# Python How to move/centralize pycache files

Tags: python

Below is what my project looks like

```
Project
  src
    folder1
      __pycache__
      ...
    folder2
      __pycache__
      ...
    main
    __pycache__

  tests
    __pycache__
      ...
```

Is there a way to centralize all the pycache files in one folder so that it looks something like this?

```
Project
  __pycache__
  src
    folder1
    folder2
    main
  tests
```

Comment: Related: Sometimes you might just want to hide the `__pycache__` in your IDE. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code) how to do that in VS Code, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516219/pycharm-hide-files-by-pattern) how to do that in PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported to put all cache files under a single subdirectory.

There is an option to put the cache directory *tree* someplace else, however.  Set [PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX):

```
export PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=/path/to/someplace/else
```

This will create the cached directory tree under `/path/to/someplace/else` and leave your project directory unlittered with `__pycache__` subdirectories.

If you want to disable caching entirely, use [PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE) instead. Note that startup times will be slightly slower, as Python would have to recompute .pyc files on every startup.

These options may also be specified via interpreter command-line options, [-X](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-X) or [-B](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-B) respectively, rather than via environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60024195/18877953)

You can set the `PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX` environment variable to the desired path.